# Does Spike Spiegel's cybernetic eye enhance his vision in any way?

Tags: anime, cowboy-bebop

It is known that he lost his right eye in an accident and he got a cybernetic eye as a replacement, but does this replacement eye help to improve his vision in any way? (Besides obviously having two eyes instead of one.)
This could be either when he's fighting, shooting, piloting his ship, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't recall any mention of enhanced sight in regards to Spike's eye, although it is noted that he has a very high visual acuity.

Here are some reasons why I believe his cybernetic eye did not improve his vision any more than his old one did though:

- He still fumbled around and couldn't see well in the dark
- When he squinted, he squinted both eyes, instead of just the non-cybernetic one (if the cybernetic one had enhanced vision, wouldn't he just close his left eye to see farther?)
- There was no explicit mention of enhanced vision from the eye in the series

In fact, the only information I could gather from the series about his eye comes from this quote from him to Faye:

> Look at my eyes, Faye. One of them is a fake because I lost it in an
>   accident. Since then, I've been seeing the past in one eye and the
>   present in the other. So, I thought I could only see patches of
>   reality, never the whole picture.

If you watch the series too, flashbacks of his life before the bebop start with a closeup of his left eye, the non-cybernetic one that supposedly only sees the past.  I'm guessing that in order not to distract from this emotional symbolism, they decided not to attach any additional importance to the eye.

Comment: There is also some speculation that he might be blind in his organic eye, and he could only afford to have the one replaced.